# Should I ask for my former boss for a reference if it seems he does not like me?

Tags: work-experience

Ok, so I did a supervisor job over the summer for 2 months. It was my first supervisor job and I would really like to use it on my resume because it looks good. However, I'm fairly sure that my former boss doesn't like me, so I'm worried about asking for a reference. Usually, because I know he doesn't like me I wouldn't ask, but seeing as this is my first supervisor job, I really need a reference for the future. Should I ask him, on the chance that he will say no? Or should I just list him on my references anyway, without asking him?

Comment: Most people give references. It is churlish not to. Whether it is a good one is a different matter. But these days due to litigation etc. they are seldom bad - usually neutral. i.e. this chap worked here from A to B.

Comment: @EdHeal Here in Australia it might be different.  References are more often than not personal references from someone you worked with or for previously.  You choose someone who will portray you professionally in a positive light rather than just confirming "Person X worked here."

Comment: @JaneS - The references that I have given as a coworker has been to confirmed that you have worked with the individual between two dates and also that they have used certain technologies. Usually this is just the completion of a form.

Personally I think that references are not worth the paper that they are written on - but that is another question, and I guess that is why employers have a probation period.

Comment: @EdHeal It would be _easier_ that way if it worked like that here :)  I've been a referee for people I've managed many times and by the time you've answered questions ranging from "What were their main strengths" to "Would you work with them again", it's quite an ordeal :/

Comment: Hi Jean, please let us know which country you are in. I have taken references from several countries. Reference laws and standards vary extremely by country. Ed's take sounds like the UK where there are tight regulations and you would be fine to list a manager who didn't like you - as companies are restricted in what they can ask and say. In Australia as Jane pointed out, references can be very detailed and you would not want to use someone who did not like you.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, *never* list someone as a reference without their permission.

Secondly, you can list the position on your CV regardless, and *ask* your old supervisor if he would be a referee for you.  If he declines, then the worst case is that you still have the position on your CV.

But it never hurts to ask.  He might surprise you :)